# WordPress Jet Engine elementor wont show CDATA[] on posting xml rss feed

Tags: xml, wordpress, rss, jet-engine

I found a problem when i want to post rss feed on my wordpress

here is the link
https://ssioltbrw.samuel.co.id/category-research-reports/emiten-report-ssi/feed/

i dont know why the CDATA is empty and thats why i cannot retrieve it with my php.
i am using jet engine elementor to make that list

i already try to change the theme and try to reconfigure the jet engine but still no avail. i have read that it is caused because the excerpt is empty.

but when i read the documentation the excerpt can automatically filled 55 words from the post